# MinGW and __uuidof

Tags: c++, visual-studio, mingw

Is there any way to simulate the __uuidof functionality from MinGW?
AFAIK __uuidof is only Visual Studio, but I need to get some GUIDs from my software and it may compile under MinGW.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use MS VS with '#import' directive just to create a tlh and tli? From these generated files you can create your own header file for MinGW and you won't be needing __uuidof any more.

Comment: Thanks natko, I think this is a good idea. It's not a smart way but I guess it will work. I find something similar in that link: http://osdir.com/ml/gnu.mingw.devel/2007-03/msg00058.html, Regards

Comment: I don't see why "not smart way". It is a COM dll, so even if you decide to replace it with a new version in the future, your header file remains the same because current IDs and interfaces should not be changed. Only new IDs and new interfaces can be added.

Answer (score 1):

[MinGW-w64](http://mingw-w64.sourceforge.net/) provides a mostly-functional `__uuidof`. I believe better support will be in GCC 4.7 once released.

Comment: rubenvb, Thanks for the suggestion. Using MinGW-64 could be a solution.